# How can I get data from multiple Siemens PLCs into Excel?

Tags: excel, reporting, plc, scada

I use Siemens WinCC SCADA system and I need to transfer data from specific addresses in a Siemens PLC into Excel for reporting purposes.

Is it worth to try doing it by programming in WinCC scada or are there any other reporting tools? My main requirements are:

- Easily define PLC and data addresses to read
- Customize report view in Excel (add logo, adjust formatting etc.)
- Having data in tabular form and in an Excel chart
- Price should not be very high

By the way, I have a small panel PC on site. This PC has 1 GB RAM and Intel Celeron CPU. The reporting application has to be running in such small PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PLC Reports [www.plcreports.com](http://www.plcreports.com). You define your reports directly in Excel and PLCReports ‘fills’ it with data. What I like is that you can use the complete Excel functionality. I even use it to run my own macros to make special calculations. Regarding your requirements: 
-   You specify the PLC definition in one Excel row – just pass the IP Address, Rack and Slot – very easy. 
-   You can add any logo and format the Excel Report as you want
-   Tabular data is possible – the Report is an Excel file :-)  -or PDF if you want
-   There is a starter version if you only need a few reports which is quite cheap.
And it runs on low performance hardware. I run it together with WinCC Flexible on a Panel PC.

Comment: I have tried PLC Reports and quite satisfied. I do not need to install any database and everything is in Excel. I liked this approach very much.

Answer (score 0):

you could use OPC, also this product can then be utilised for other PLC's -- http://www.matrikonopc.com/products/opc-archiving/excel-reporter.aspx

Comment: As far as I see, Matrikon's Excel reporter generates excel files manually. Do you know if it is possible to insert data into Excel like Excel file is a database file?

Comment: I would not use Excel as a database - an OPC Historian would be a clean solution for your storage needs and you then can use whatever presentation package you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use S7 Excel Connect, it's a Microsoft Excel add-in and can directly read and write data from a S7 PLC without the need of any other OPC or other software.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30240169)